# How to create rain in GLSL or similar?

Tags: glsl, webgl, hlsl

Is there any great tutorial out there on how to create rain in GLSL or a similar shader? I can find ones easily for Maya but not for this, sadly. Thanks!

Comment: What are these Maya tutorials?  I really doubt that has anything to do with a shader, and instead is all about particle effects.

Comment: Yeah, I believe it was more about particle effects, just in application with a rain-like look, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "rain". There are lots of ways to represent rain

This sample has a rain effect and a ripple effect

https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/registry/trunk/public/webgl/sdk/demos/google/particles/index.html

No tutorial though. It works by creating a bunch of unit squares, giving each one an random value, adding that random value to a time value and the computing a position in the shader as in

```
uniform float u_time;          // a time value passed in by JavaScript
uniform mat4 u_view_inverse;   // view inverse (camera world matrix)
uniform mat4 u_view_projection;// view projection matrix

attribute vec4 a_vertex;       // the unit quad values
attribute vec4 a_position;     // the base position of this particle repeated for
                               // each vertex
attribute vec4 a_velocity;     // velocity for this quad, repeated for each vertex
attribute float a_time_offset; // a time offset for this particle 
                               // repeated for each vertex

// compute a position
float localTime = u_time + a_time_offset;
vec4 base_position = a_position + a_velocity * localTime;

// rotate quad so it's perpendicular to the view
vec4 quadX = viewInverse[0] * a_vertex.x;
vec4 quadZ = viewInverse[1] * a_vertex.y;

// compute the real world position for this vertex
vec4 position = base_position + quadX + quadZ;

// at this point position is the same as any other 'standard' 3d shader
// do with it whatever. Example:
gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * position;
```

Sorry if that's too terse.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome, gman!! Thanks so much! Did you create this yourself?

Comment: Oh, and sorry, where is the random value passed in? Or am I just overlooking something obvious?

Comment: In the demo linked to, yes there is are several semi random value passed in as other attributes for each particle. They are chosen at initialization time so each particle effect is really playing the same "loop" of particles over and over but the effects look good. If you need to place multiples of the same effect around a world and you don't want to have them all look in sync the easiest thing to do is (a) give each one a separate clock and (b) give each one a random rotation